# SQL - uniquely select (possibly missing) children in a hierarchy

Tags: sql, join, view, hierarchy

I have a simple hierarchy of `component` in MySQL which is described by a table `assembly`.

```
SELECT * FROM component;

+----+--------+------+
¦ id ¦ name   ¦ type ¦
+----+--------+------+
¦ 11 ¦ car1   ¦ A    ¦
¦ 12 ¦ car2   ¦ A    ¦
¦ 13 ¦ car3   ¦ A    ¦
¦ 21 ¦ motor1 ¦ B    ¦
¦ 22 ¦ motor2 ¦ B    ¦
¦ 31 ¦ brake1 ¦ C    ¦
+----+--------+------+

SELECT * FROM assembly;

+----+-----------+----------+
¦ id ¦ parent_id ¦ child_id ¦
+----+-----------+----------+
¦  1 ¦        11 ¦       21 ¦
¦  2 ¦        12 ¦       22 ¦
¦  3 ¦        11 ¦       31 ¦
¦  4 ¦        13 ¦       31 ¦
+----+-----------+----------+
```

EDIT : As Dems correctly guessed, the third entry (id = 3) was missing in the original post. The table is now complete.

I want to generate a list of all cars with the name of its motor, if any. Each car should appear once.

Desired output :

```
+----------+------------+
¦ car_name ¦ motor_name ¦
+----------+------------+
¦     car1 ¦     motor1 ¦
¦     car2 ¦     motor2 ¦
¦     car3 ¦            ¦
+----------+------------+
```

Is there a simple way to obtain this ?

A car has at most one motor child.

An outer join with a view on motor components yields two rows for `car1` and this should not happen :

```
CREATE VIEW comp_motor
AS 
SELECT * FROM component
WHERE type='B';

SELECT parent.name, child.name
FROM component parent
LEFT JOIN assembly a ON parent.id = a.parent.id
LEFT JOIN comp_motor child ON a.child_id = child.id
WHERE 
parent.type = 'A';
```

This gives

```
+------+--------+
¦ name ¦   name ¦
+------+--------+
¦ car1 ¦ motor1 ¦
¦ car1 ¦ NULL   ¦
¦ car2 ¦ motor2 ¦
¦ car3 ¦ NULL   ¦ 
+------+--------+
```

The second row should not be there. Of course `DISTINCT` is not going to help in this case.

I cannot change the database structure.

Any input would be most welcome !

Comment: you should be using inner join if you don't want second row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please run the following SELECT statement and tell us what you get?

```
SELECT * FROM component WHERE type = 'A'
```

I think you have `Car1` in there twice...

**EDIT**

Oh, or you have two records for Car1 in the assembly table?  What does this show?

```
SELECT * FROM assembly WHERE parent_id = 11
```

If that's the source, try this...

```
SELECT
  parent.name,
  child.name
FROM
  component parent
LEFT JOIN
  (
    assembly a 
  INNER JOIN
    comp_motor child
      ON a.child_id = child.id
  )
    ON parent.id = a.parent.id
WHERE 
  parent.type = 'A';
```

Comment: You pointed out the exact error in the original post, thanks a lot. I now corrected it. There was a missing entry in the `assembly` table. Your solution gives exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select car.name car_name, coalesce(motor.name, 'No motor') motor_name
from component car
left join (select a.parent_id, c.name
           from assembly a
           inner join component c 
                   on a.child_id = c.id and c.type = 'B') motor
       on car.id = motor.parent_id
where car.type = 'A'
```